# What is this success method? (Swift Closure)

Tags: swift, swifty-json

So I copy pasted some code from Ray Wenderlich's Swifty JSON tutorial and haven't been able to understand some of the calls I am making.

I've scanned through the SwiftyJSON library, I looked at the NSURL description on the developer site and I checked out the Swift guide but I either can't find it or I get a bunch of miscellania back.

What do these success calls mean?

```
    func getIndexWithSuccess(success: ((indexData: NSData!) -> Void)) {
        loadDataFromURL(NSURL(string: url)!, completion:{(data, error) -> Void in
            if let urlData = data {
                /* HERE */
                success(indexData: urlData)
            }
        })
    }

    func loadDataFromURL(url: NSURL, completion:(data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void) {
        var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        let loadDataTask = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if let responseError = error {
                completion(data: nil, error: responseError)
            } else if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                if httpResponse.statusCode != 200 {
                    var statusError = NSError(domain:"com.raywenderlich",
                        code:httpResponse.statusCode,
                        userInfo:[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "HTTP status code has unexpected value."])
                    completion(data: nil, error: statusError)
                } else {
                    completion(data: data, error: nil)
                }
            }
        })
        loadDataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please restrict your question to *one problem*.

Comment: I once tried a couple of those "Ray Wenderlich" demos. None worked. Look for another source.

Comment: @ThomasKilian - worked for me. I just don't know what the success call means!

Comment: @MartinR - just did, much clearer, thanks for the pointer

Comment: Just wanted to toss in my 2 cents. It was due to such things that I gave up there. But if it works for you, fine :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that it says:

```
func getIndexWithSuccess(success: ((indexData: NSData!) -> Void)) {
```

That means success is a parameter. What follows after the colon is a closure.

`success`, therefore is a closure.

Now, how should we interpret that closure?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

Note, the above closure includes some extra parentheses for clarity.

You can leave shorten the above by removing them:

```
func getIndexWithSuccess(success: (indexData: NSData!) -> Void) {
```

More helpful links:

http://fuckingclosuresyntax.com

http://fuckingswiftblocksyntax.com

Edit:

Perhaps the clearest explanation in this context is by rearranging it like this:

```
func getIndexWithSuccess(
    success: (
        data: [DoctorModel]
    )->(
        Void
    ),
    moreInfo: String = "This is another parameter, but the trailing closure technique wont work"
) {
```

The above complies. But the moreInfo parameter is also true. Trailing closures won't work. By rearranging the parameters so the closure is last, you can use the trailing closure technique.

Comment: @ThomasKilian - this is what I know so far ;)